# Solving a differential equation (chain rule?)

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I came across a diff. equation which (I think) is just an application of chain rule, but I'm quite confused. Here is the situation:

Let $F=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ be a real vector field acting on a complex function $\rho$ as $F(\rho)=\rho^{2}$. Define further the complex functions $\alpha,\beta,\tau$ as

$\alpha=\rho\alpha_{0}-\pi_{0}+\rho^{2}\overline{\tau}_{0}$

$\beta=\overline{\rho}\beta_{0}$

$\pi=\pi_{0}+\overline{\tau}_{0}\rho^{2}$

where the zero-indices indicate that it's independent of $s$.

Using this information I'm trying to solve the first order differential equation

$F(W)=\overline{\rho}W+\overline{\pi}-\overline{\alpha}-\beta$

and show that the solution is

$W=\overline{\rho}W_{0}+\overline{\alpha}_{0}+\beta_{0}-\overline{\pi}_{0}/\overline{\rho}$

I can check that it's indeed the solution by substituting it back into the diff. equation, but quite confused on how to obtain it myself. I know how to integrate by parts and I also know the chain rule, but somehow here it's confusing.

This is not homework.